# MVVM-Light/WPF Navigation Application

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, navigation, mvvm-light

As I write a WPF application with MVVM Light, I'm trying to determine the best way to allow for Navigation in the application. I've been reading about creating Services, Interfaces, and Helpers, but unfortunately my head still hasn't grasped the great advice being offered on SO. I got down a spiral of starting with a simple class and some code behind to use MEF and/or Unity to accomplish my task.

What do you find to be the simplest way to add basic Navigation of a frame to an MVVM Light application built on WPF?

Comment: If you found a good way of navigating then please post it

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems light, but it's hard. The solution must cover several aspects as navigating to an existing view, closing a view, injecting the viewmodel before navigating to the view, animated transitions, etc.

[image] Please check out [Magellan](http://www.paulstovell.com/magellan) a WPF framework created by [Paul Stovell](http://www.paulstovell.com/) that covers all this issues and more!

Answer (score 0):

A simple navigation mvvm-light navigation demo.
https://bitbucket.org/dbeattie/navdemo/src